Big Query: Issue with PowerBi conector showing al projects
When login with an oauth, I am able to see all BigQuery projects even those I dont have access.
I see the projects, but I cannot access the tables. Also, I cannot access the tables in which I have permission.
This does not happen if I connect using a service account instead of an organizational account
I expected to see only the projects in which I have access to

Let's imagine that Power BI only showed the projects which contains tables you have have query ability.  How could that work?  Google Cloud doesn't have an API to list such projects ... instead, Power BI would have to internally list all projects ... for every project it would have to list all datasets and for all datasets list all tables ... and then determine if your identity has access.  This computationally expensive and would likely dramatically slow down the user experience.   Instead, it is likely Power BI lists the tables you can see and expects you to know if it contains the table you want.
A table is identified by the tripple of:

Project Name
Dataset Name
Table Name

As such, if you are using Power BI, it is likely that you already know the table you want and hence the tripple.
Getting back to your original question ... if you DO want to restict the list of projects shown, then you can talk to your Google Cloud administrator and have them change the permissions so that you can only see/list projects that have been explicitly allowed for you to see.  It is likely that your admin has given you permissions to list ALL projects in your organization and that is why you are are seeing all.  Your admin CAN give you access to see/list just a subset of projects and it is only these that will show up.   Details of this story and how to achieve it can be found at Listing all projects and folders in your hierarchy.
